# Get form input value from webpage of chrome extension MV3

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building chrome extension MV3. I am successful in changing the content and sending information from particular page to the destination. In my code inside `content.js` I need API key from user who would be installing this extension in his browser. I am displaying the `welcome.html` page which contains the form to collect the required info from user first time only when extension is installed.

Here is relevant code in my `manifest.json`:

```
"permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "scripting"
    ],
"background": [
        {
            "service_worker": [
                "background.js",
                "welcome.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ],
```

In my `background.js` I have:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function (details) {
    if (details.reason === "install") {
      // Code to be executed on first install
      // eg. open a tab with a url
      chrome.tabs.create({
        url: "welcome.html"        
      });
    } else if (details.reason === "update") {
      // When extension is updated
      console.log("Updated to new version")
      
    }
  });
```

and in `welcome.html` I have

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome to My Extension</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="welcome.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Welcome to CRC to Lob Power Tool</h1>
        <h2>Here you can automate your letters sending without any hastle. By using this tool you agree to share your lob API key with our system. Don't worry we do not leak your private information.</h2>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form id="formdata">
            <fieldset>
                <p>
                    <label for="">Your Email : </label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" align="left">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="">Live API Key:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="APIkey" name="APIkey" align="left">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input id="ok_btn" type="submit">
                </p>
                <p style="border:1px solid red; padding: 5px;"><b>Note:</b> You must submit Live API Key carefully, it
                    is one time setup against your purchase.</p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="details">
        
    </div>
    
</body>
```

what should go in `welcome.js` so that the input at `id="APIkey"` should become the part of `content.js` file, and can be used in future even the browser is closed, when the button having an `id="ok_btn"` in `welcome.html`is clicked? I have declared variable `var APIkey` inside `content.js` but couldn't hit luck in understanding how to establish connection between all of the above stuff. I have read documentation from [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/) as well but didn't get it properly.

Tried following in `welcome.js` but hit an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

`welcome.js`

```
document.getElementById("ok_btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").Value;
    var APIKey = document.getElementById("APIKey").Value;
    document.getElementById("details").innerHTML(email ," ", APIKey);
   return (email, APIKey);
}, true);
```

Comment: Use [chrome.storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage). Also fix your `background` inmanifest.json per the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/architecture-overview/).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. One thing want to ask is that would the data be stored as cookies or it would become the part of content.js when chrome.stotage API is used.